# Creating custom SVG Icons in colour and generating the correct HTML with the required classes for the font file

Tags: c#, html, svg, blazor, webfonts

Our company wants me to create a font package with our own custom icons for our Blazor application.

They don't want to reference individual image files as this will mean the browser will have to do multiple https request to fetch each individual file. We are using a menu sidebar with many sub-level items with icons.

Normally, when you create a Black and White SVG icon and generate a font package (lets say on https://icomoon.io/), it will just give you one span tag with one class because it is a black an white icon.

For example:

```
<span class="icon-BW-View-Customer"></span>
```

Below is the icon.

[image]

When I generate a font package for a colour image, it will create a parent span tag with sub-level span tags with sub-classes.

Now the issue I am trying to resolve is, when I dynamically create the menu items, I need to know if the icon is in colour and how many sub classes it has so that I can loop and add the sub CSS classes and span tags. Is there a way I can check the amount of CSS Query selectors somehow so that I can know how many times my code needs to loop to add these span tags dynamically?

Here is an example of the colour icon I just created for testing purposes with many paths and colours:

[image]

This is the CSS classes Icon moon will generate for colour icons:
The issue here is that I need to know how many paths the style.css file contains so that I can build the HTML markup dynamically. (Below this CSS, I have added an example of how they are nested).

```
.icon-Colour-Icon .path1:before {
 content: "\e900";
 color: #2e3192;
 }
.icon-Colour-Icon .path2:before {
 content: "\e901";
 color: #be1e2d;
 margin-left: -1em;
 }
 .icon-Colour-Icon .path3:before {
 content: "\e902";
 color: #00a14b;
 margin-left: -1em;
 }
.icon-Colour-Icon .path4:before {
 content: "\e903";
 color: #00a14b;
 margin-left: -1em;
 }
 .icon-Colour-Icon .path5:before {
 content: "\e904";
 color: #8b5e3c;
 margin-left: -1em;
 }
.icon-Colour-Icon .path6:before {
 content: "\e905";
 color: #f9ed32;
 margin-left: -1em;
 }
```

Nested Span tags with different path classes:

```
<span class="icon-Colour-Icon">
 <span class="path1"></span>
 <span class="path2"></span>
 <span class="path3"></span>
 <span class="path4"></span>
 <span class="path5"></span>
 <span class="path6"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: How important is it to load .svg files, rather than using inline `<svg>`  If you are willing to do it inline (which will prevent caching the icons however, but if they are just a couple kb each that doesn't matter too much), then you will very easily have control over any part of the .svg presentation that you want-- making it extremely easy to change colors and so on, and even to add or change animation parameters.  Then you won't need any nested spans or complex calculations.

Answer (score 2):

I think your requirements are a little flawed as svg's will be cached after first load.

In answering your question.
Using svg's `<use href="" ...` :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol class="bi bi-binoculars" viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="binoculars">
   ...
  </symbol>
  <symbol class="bi bi-caret-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="caret-left">
    ...
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Razor Component

```
<svg class="bi" width=@Size height=@Size fill="currentColor" @attributes=@UncapturedAttributes >
     <use href="_content/ChatClient.Core/images/bootstrap-icons/application-bootstrap-icons.svg#binoculars" ></use>
</svg>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Size { get; set; } = 24;

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> UncapturedAttributes { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

I use this technique in this [wasm pwa](https://brianlparker.github.io/BlazorIconGenerator/) hosted on github pages. It creates a subset of twitters bootstrap icons.

I pass there existing svg using:

```
        using var reader = new StreamReader(content);

        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(reader);

        XElement svgElement = document.Root!;

        foreach (var element in svgElement.Elements().ToList())
        {
 ...
        }
```